# back button hidden when adding left button ios

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to add left bar button between back button and nav. bar title. I am using setLeftBarButtonItem. When I use this it hides the back button.

Any idea how to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to YES

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.